R studio not installing spark (sparklyr)
**I am trying to use apache spark with R, using the sparklyr package.
When I use the spark_install() function, it starts downloading a file from internet. But the download never finishes and results in an error.**
I've loade the sparklyr package in R and used this function
spark_install()
This was the response, the downloaded started:
Installing Spark 3.5.1 for Hadoop 3 or later.
Downloading from:

'https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.5.1/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz'
Installing to:
'~/spark/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3'
trying URL 'https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.5.1/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz'

But after 2 or 3 minutes this error pops up.
Error in download.file(...) :
cannot open URL 'https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.5.1/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz'
I've tried with different versions and the resulting error is pratically the same:
Installing Spark 3.5.0 for Hadoop 3 or later.
Downloading from:

'https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.5.0/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz'
Installing to:
'~/spark/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3'
trying URL 'https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.5.0/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 400395283 bytes (381.8 MB)
====
downloaded 32.0 MB

Error in download.file(...) :
download from 'https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.5.0/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz' failed
